# Spring Security Authorization Server

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2, private-key, authorization-server, spring-resource-server

my question about new `Spring-Security-Authorization-Server`, i create auth-server and resource-server, and generating public and private keys in auth-server. I set jwkSetUri in resource-server, can't understand how resource-server checks token. Who understood how the verification principle works, how should I implement it correctly?

My purpose get correct implementation of new auth server and resource server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after reading the book how to work with asymmetric keys, we generate a token based on public and private keys in the `auth-server`, and we have an address for the public key `/oauth2/jwks` with which the `resource-server` checks whether this jwt is really generated by `auth-server`